# table not found in sqlite3 database in windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, sqlite, windows-phone

I am trying to retrieve data from Sqlite3 database in my windows phone 8 application. I have used db file in the project folder and following is the code:

```cs
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "my1stapp.db"), true);

SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from testtable";
List<Task> retrievedTasks = sqlCommand.ExecuteQuery<Task>();
myTextBox.Text = retrievedTasks.ToString();
```

But still its throwing exception saying table testtable not foud, but table do exists. Also the build action in properties of the db file is changed to content. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "my1stapp.db"), true);
Statement st = SQLite3.Prepare2(conn.Handle, "select * from testtable");
var result = SQLite3.Step(st);
//Check the result value (Row / Done / etc.)
SQLite3.Finalize(st);
conn.Dispose();
```

You can create your DB at the beginning of your app/process:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path))
        {
            connection.CreateTable<Table1>();
            connection.CreateTable<Table2>();
            //more tables...
        }
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, I tried to use the code that you mentioned above, but the problem still persists. I did some research and it seems that, for some reason when I debug the app, it tries to create table on the given path by itself and since its creating database on its own, the table would not be present there by throwing the exception. Let me know your thoughts/inputs if you have any

Comment: Maybe my question might sounds obvious, but do you create by yourself a DB file containing tables before? If not, let me know, I can put an example for you.

Comment: Yes I did create an db file by myself and copied into project folder. I thought "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path" would point to the db file I copied, but doesn't seem to be working in that way.

Comment: Ok, so my suggestion is to create the DB programmatically at the beginning of your process, of course you can check if the DB exists and not creating it in that case. In my example, I expect to the classes representing the tables. Example: see my answer edited.